# Is it possible to append kernel args when booting linux VM on vSphere?

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I'd like to get rid of prompt '**Continue with autoinstall (yes/no)?**' while installing VMs using **cloud-init** on **vSphere** without messing with crafted boot image.

On other systems it could be achieved with **kvm ... -append 'autoinstall'**, **qemu-system-x86_64 ... -append 'autoinstall'** or **virt-install ... --extra-args 'autoinstall'**, but I haven't seen anything like that for **vSphere**.

Is it possible at all to append kernel args there?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting creative. Try this.

1. Have a VM installed with VMware Tools up and running.
2. Create the new VM but leave it powered off.
3. Use your preferred method to attach the disk to the running VM. PowerCLI would work, or do it from the UI if you rather. Here is a PowerCLI example to get you going.

```
$disk = Get-VM {poweredOffVM}| Get-HardDisk
Get-VM {PoweredOnVM} | New-HardDisk -DiskPath $disk.filename
```

4. Edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf`, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` or whatever you need. I don't really know what you want to change exactly, but here is an example of using Invoke-VMscript. The grub example is just that. I didn't test if is a valid config. I'm guessing you can pull the files from a VM with your OS that was already created and go from there.

```
Invoke-VMScript -VM {poweredOnVM} -GuestUser {root/admin} -GuestPassword {password} -ScriptText 'cat <<EOF > /boot/grub.cfg
default=autoinstall
timeout=5
timeout_style=menu

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Focal Live Installer - automated" --id=autoinstall {
    echo "Loading Kernel...1111"
    linux /vmlinuz  root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000  ip=dhcp url=http://10.10.11.245/tftp/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://10.10.11.245/tftp/ ---
    echo "Loading Ram Disk...111"
    initrd /initrd
}
menuentry "Focal Live Installer" --id=install {
    echo "Loading Kernel...22"
    linux /vmlinuz   root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://10.10.11.245/tftp/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso
    echo "Loading Ram Disk...22"
    initrd /initrd
}
EOF
'
```

Other than that I don't know a better way. I think most people have an image all setup and then use guest customization, or create an OVA and use vApp options to pull the user configs.